# Downscoring an answer removed a point from me

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I did my first down vote on an answer and it removed a point from my reputation. Is this a glitch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  That is the expected result, as it ensures people don't [downvote answers without consideration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting).  Downvotes on questions, however, are "free" and don't cost you any reputation.

From the [Help Center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> **You lose reputation when**:
>
> - you vote down an answer: −1